# Exception "Device doesn't support multi-window, can not reparent task=Task..."

Tags: android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FooActivity.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

The above code works fine most of the time. It occasionally (very rarely) throws the following exception:

```
Exception: Device doesn't support multi-window, can not reparent task=Task{96bc4dd #439 type=undefined A=10304:net.mydomain.myapp U=0 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1} to root-task=Task{5be86f #4 type=undefined ?? U=0 rootTaskId=3 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=multi-window stage=main/left translucent=true sz=0}
Class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Device doesn't support multi-window, can not reparent task=Task{96bc4dd #439 type=undefined A=10304:net.mydomain.myapp U=0 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1} to root-task=Task{5be86f #4 type=undefined ?? U=0 rootTaskId=3 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=multi-window stage=main/left translucent=true sz=0}
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3027)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3007)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2990)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2932)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1801)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5596)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5554)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:735)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6052)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6019)
```

This one happened on a Samsung Galaxy A52 5G.

Could anyone shed some light on the possible cause?